# Read Only Database Connection with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, readonly

Is it possible to use Hibernate and connect to a database with a read only connection?  I will be working on a project that will require connecting to an existing database, pulling data from it, and doing some complex data manipulation in the application.  Throughout all of this I can`t change anything in the database, hence the read only connection requirement.

My first thought was to pull the data from the database using Hibernate so that I can have ready made Java objects represent the data, however, I can`t seem to find any information on how to force Hibernate to use a read only database connection ... I have a feeling this might actually be impossible, but I want to find out from others before I pursue other ideas.

Comment: If you are using a framework like spring you can set the transaction to be readonly

Comment: I think you can also set datasource to be readonly.. but it works depending on driver

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, apparently :(

But responding to your comment about the cases where Hibernate may still write back to the DB, you could manually detach the object from your persistence context, after which Hibernate would cease caring about the state of the object & whether its been modified.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: Session.setDefaultReadOnly( true );

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/readonly.html#readonly-api-loaddefault

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, if you read the whole section (especially Table 11.1) you`ll notice that there are cases where Hibernate will still write to the database even though the session was set to load things read only ... what I`m hoping to achieve is a way to make 100% sure that Hibernate will not write anything to the database.

Comment: Correct, but from what I see there is generally problem only with    *-many association.
"
Hibernate dirty-checks unidirectional one-to-many and many-to-many associations;

The collection can contain entities that are read-only, as well as entities that are not read-only.

Entities can be added and removed from the collection; changes are flushed to the database.
"
It seems that all you should be watching for is not to add(and remove) entities from collections, the existing one could be made readonly as well

Answer (score 0):

To be bullet-proof safe against anything you do in the application, you need to assign read-only permissions to the DB user that Hibernate is configured to use. This has to be done on the database side. Otherwise, if you rely only on the configuration on the application side, you can always make a mistake (forget to detach the entities, forget to set the session to read-only mode etc.).